# No AMI selected after AWS EC2 instance created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I selected the Amazon Linux AMI when I was creating the AWS EC2 instance:

[image]

But there is no AMI in my EC2 dashboard after I created the instance. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

What could be reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are filtering the images view according to "Owned by me" and this image is a public one, owned by AWS. Since you don't have any private images, the view is empty.

If you switch to the instances view (select it on the left) you will see your new instance with the AMI you chose.

If you want to create your own image, you can do this by creating an AMI from your running instance. This new AMI will be owned by you.